# Connect to local Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with QGIS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, qgis

I am running SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and 2.18.16 version of QGIS. When I attempt Layer -> Add Layer -> SQL Server layer and click new:

- Connection name: Local
- Provider/DSN blank
- Host: Localhost

Clicking "List Databases" shows a - "Server does not exist or access denied" error that disappears really fast. Other processes I am using can connect to the database fine (although this had an option for Windows Authentication). I have also tried enabling TCP/IP and named pipes in the management studio options

Comment: Host (local) and tick Trusted Connection (to use windows auth)? What is your server / instance name for sql server if you run Sql Server Configuration Manager and view SQL Server Services?

Comment: If I am looking at the right thing it is "MSSQLSERVER"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the settings in the services did fix it, I just neglected to restart the service. The local database now shows up